# too many redirect occurred when accessing from mobile browser

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, http-redirect

I am using wprdpress plugin WPtouch for the responsive website. When i open mobile page it redirect many times so it could not able to shoe result.

I am trying to make changes on .htaccess file but still not reaching on result.
here is my .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.xdsavings.com/mobile-app
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xdsavings.com/mobile-app/ [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure `HTTP_HOST` contains a path? Because if not, your condition won't prevent it from redirecting over and over again.

It seems like you should be using `REQUEST_URI` and checking for `/mobile-app`, or something to that order...

On a separate note as a smartphone and tablet user, I'd add that being served a subpar, dumbed down version of a site on those perfectly capable devices yields terrible user experience. If you *really* want a mobile version of your site, use a responsive html/css design with `@media` queries as appropriate.

Comment: thanks for the response.
we are already using @media query in appropriate way bu url which we want to redirect in redirect many times before comes to mobile url.